# Customizing detection change

Tags: hibernate

I can now if a session contain any changes which must be synchronized with the database with 
session.isDirty()

But i have a simple field (modification date) that i would like to be ignore by it.
Example: object Person( name,age,datemodification).

if i just modify the datemodification field i would like that session.isDirty() or othermethod like this to return false so at the end no sql update will occur.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Hibernate Annotations you could annotate *datemodification* with ***@Transient*** which would mean any changes to that field would not be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would need to use an Interceptor and override the onFlushDirty() method. [This](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=983217) looks like a forum that discusses the same question.